# Set project stage for JavaServer Faces with JNDI configuration/lookup in Glassfish v3

Tags: jsf, glassfish, jndi

I'm trying to set the project stage for JavaServer Faces in a GlassFish application server v3 with a JNDI property.

I set the stage property to **Development** stage, but my application received always the **Production** stage.

[image]

I use GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 (build 43) on a windows system.

For rendering the project stage in the JSF page I use this:

```
<h:outputText value="Stage:#{facesContext.application.projectStage}"/>
```

Is anything else necessary to use the project stage in an application? The application has no web.xml file.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is correct, but instead of `stage=Development`, use `value = Development`,
i.e. replace `stage` with `value` in the property name field.

Answer (score 1):

You need this in your web.xml. It works with 'stage' then.

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jsf/ProjectStage</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>java.lang.String</res-type>
        <mapped-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</mapped-name>
</resource-ref>
```

This maps the global JNDI property of GF to the reference lookup in JSF.

Answer (score 0):

As a minimum, the following entry needs to be in `web.xml`:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jsf/ProjectStage</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>java.lang.String</res-type>
    <mapped-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</mapped-name>
</resource-ref>
```

The property name depends on what factory class you use:

- Use `value=Development` for `org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory`
- Use `stage=Development` for `com.sun.faces.application.ProjectStageJndiFactory`

You can also set the resources using `asadmin`:

```
C:\glassfish5\bin> asadmin.bat create-custom-resource --restype java.lang.String --factoryclass org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory --property "value=Development" javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE

C:\glassfish5\bin> asadmin.bat create-custom-resource --restype java.lang.String --factoryclass com.sun.faces.application.ProjectStageJndiFactory --property "stage=Development" javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE
```