# Set Project Stage with JNDI on Glassfish 4.1

Tags: jsf, glassfish, jndi

I am looking for setting project stage on Glassfish (v4.1.1 build 1) with JNDI configuration to allow my servers to have each one, a different project stage and allow me to push modifications with Git without changing javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE in web.xml at each push.

I already tried things in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491904/set-project-stage-for-javaserver-faces-with-jndi-configuration-lookup-in-glassfi) but it appears that it does not work, maybe because it is not the same Glassfish version.

in web.xml (in my project)

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jsf/ProjectStage</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>java.lang.String</res-type>
    <mapped-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</mapped-name>
</resource-ref>
```

in domain.xml (domain used by my server)

```
<custom-resource factory-class="com.sun.faces.application.ProjectStageJndiFactory" res-type="java.lang.String" jndi-name="javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE">
    <property name="stage" value="Development"></property>
</custom-resource>
```

I also tried with `<property name="value" value="Development"></property>` instead of `name="stage"`.

but, when i am displaying `#{facesContext.application.projectStage}`, it appears as `Production` as it looks as the default stage.

Hopefully, you could help me, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem !

It appears than creating the JNDI resource on manually editing the `domain.xml` file does not create the resource properly as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51038324/jndi-lookup-on-glassfish-4-1-1-custom-resources).

So it is working properly with the JNDI custom resource created with the asadmin command.

JNDI custom resource creating command

```
create-custom-resource --restype java.lang.String --factoryclass com.sun.faces.application.ProjectStageJndiFactory --property "stage=Development" javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jsf/ProjectStage</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>java.lang.String</res-type>
    <mapped-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</mapped-name>
</resource-ref>
```