# JNDI lookup on Glassfish 4.1.1 custom resources

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jndi

I am trying to use JNDI custom resources to store data directly in my server (Glassfish) but it is apparently not working.

I define my JNDI as on the image below

[image]

which corresponds to the following description in my domain.xml.

```
<custom-resource factory-class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory" res-type="java.lang.String" jndi-name="projectStage">
      <property name="value" value="UnitTest"></property>
</custom-resource>
```

And then, i am trying to get this value in one of my managed bean.

```
Context c = new InitialContext();
c.lookup("projectStage");
```

But... `javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'projectStage'` is the only thing i get from it.

If anyone has an idea for me, i will be thankful !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved !

I was editing my domain.xml manually to add my JNDI custom resource as Glassfish 4.1.1 administration interface gives an Runtime error when clicking on **New...** on the JNDI Custom Resource section.

Once the `domain.xml` file edited, it was displayed well in the administration panel but apparently not properly working.

I have created the custom resource with the `create-custom-resource` command of the asadmin console explains [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gglpq.html#giowe).

```
create-custom-resource --restype java.lang.String --factoryclass org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory --property "value=UnitTest" projectStage
```

And then it looks to be properly added to the system. (looks like it is not only stored in the `domain.xml` file)

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem when transfering configuration manually between an older glassfish version and Glassfish 4.1.

Your suggested solution do work but it is a lot of work if you have a lot of properties. But adding it via *asadmin* and comparing *domain.xml* I found the reason for the failure.

If you just add *custom-resource* glassfish wont be able to find it. It also need to have a reference to the resource.
In my case it was in the *<server>* part, which needed a

> <resource-ref ref="projectStage"></resourceRef>